# Chrome does not open after running a Django project using a batch file

Tags: python, google-chrome, batch-file, command-line

I use the following code in a batch file to run and open my Django project in Chrome browser:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /k "cd /d E:\Python\Python36\aiGrapes\Scripts & activate & cd /d    E:\Python\Python36\aiGrapes\sk-gdelt-project\webproject & python manage.py runserver"
start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin"
```

After running the batch file, the command windows shows Django project running successfully and:

```
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

But Chrome does not open. This also happens when I try Firefox. I suppose after the line where the manage.py is requested to run, I should add something for it to work?

Comment: try `start "" cmd /k "cd /d E:\Python\Pyt....`

Comment: @GerhardBarnard Thank you it works. But it doesn't wait for the django project to do its running which takes 2 to 3 second. How can I tell it to wait for 3 seconds then open chrome?

Comment: let me post an answer instead... but does the first process need to remain open?

Comment: Sure. I am afraid I dont understand what you mean by remaining open?

Comment: [`start`](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) features a `/WAIT` option that might be interesting; also check out its `/D` option, so you could avoid the `cd` command; finally, for the `cmd` window to close replace `/K` by `/C`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There would be a few better ways to do this, but to just make it work as is:

```
@ECHO OFF
cmd /k "cd /d E:\Python\Python36\aiGrapes\Scripts & activate & cd /d E:\Python\Python36\aiGrapes\sk-gdelt-project\webproject & start python manage.py runserver | ping -n 10 localhost & start "Chrome" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin""
```

To hide the windows, do create a file called `hideme.vbs`

add these lines:

```
Set MyScript    = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MyScript.Run "C:\Your path\yourfile.bat", 0, False
```

Ensure to add the correct path and file name to your batch file, now simply launch the vbs file instead of the batch to run everything in background.

Comment: The error was because my batch file name included spaces. Its OK now and it does'nt show the extra command window. But the python command window still shows up for the project running. Wonder how could we tell it to hide that! Anyway, I asked 1 question and you taught me three new things. Thanks again

Comment: Well. It will open by itself as it is a seperate process. You could replicate the hideme vbs and call python from there but not sure if it will work.

Comment: `python.exe` is compiled as CUI (console user interface) while `pythonw.exe` is compiled as GUI (graphical user interface). The later does not show a console window.